# How to make a combotimer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game currently and I got stuck while I was thinking about a combotimer.

Now in my game, there are enemies that run through my character and I hit them. Yet, at some point, if I can correctly hit the enemies, I want to add a powerful combo option like hitting them without any difficulty. I thought like I can create a class or a value that keeps the correct hits and let's say it's 5. When it reaches 5, then I can change the hitting options. Yet, where I'm stuck is that how I can identify after how many hits or seconds the combo can end. And in here what came to my mind is that I can make it with time. So here's the thing. I want to detect 5 hits and then I want a combotimer which makes the value of 5 decreased. So that when the value reaches 0 then I can continue to play my game with the normal standards of it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't provide anything here is what I would do as dummy code. This does

- Everytime you hit an enemy check the time since last hit
- If under the maximum delay => add to combo
- If not reset the combo counter and start over
- If reaching enough hits => enable `isSuperCombo`
- Over time reset the `isSuperCombo`
- As long as you are `isSuperCombo` you can still add hits even if they happen after the normal `maxTimeBetweenHits` to enlarge the duration of `isSuperCombo` as a little bonus

Something like

```
public class ComboCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isSuperCombo;
     
    // Maimum delay in seconds since the hit for counting the current hit as combo
    [SerializeField] private float maxTimeBetweenHits = 1;
    // Requried hits in one combo in order to activate power bonus
    [SerializeField] private int hitsUntilSuperCombo = 5;
    // Delay in seconds to reset the powerup after the last hit
    [SerializeField] private float powerUpDuration = 5;

    private int hitCounter;
    private float lastHitTime;
    private float powerUpResetTimer;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(isSuperCombo)
        {
            powerUpResetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(powerUpResetTimer <= 0)
            {
                isSuperCombo = false;
                hitCounter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Call when you hit an enemy
    public void AddHit()
    {
        if(Time.time - lastHitTime < maxTimeBetweenHits)
        {
            // then add to the hit counter
            hitCounter++;

            if(hitCounter >= hitsUntilSuperCombo)
            {
                isSuperCombo = true;
                powerUpResetTimer = powerUpDuration;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise the delay was too big => not a combo anymore
            // => Reset the counter and start over with this hit as the first one
            hitCounter = 1;
        }
        
        // update the lastHitTime
        lastHitTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

Then you could e.g. in another class check something like

```
public void CauseDamage(Enemy enemy)
{
    enemy.health -= GetComponent<ComboCounter>().isSuperCombo ? 4 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to note 5 seconds of increased damage you can use coroutine

```
private float _damage = 10;

public void StartCombo(float duration = 5)
{
    StartCoroutine(ComboHandler(duration));
}

private IEnumerator ComboHandler(float duration)
{
    _damage *= 2; //_damage = _damage * 2;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration); //wait necessary amount of real time
    _damage /= 2; //_damage = _damage / 2;
}
```

If you need to do only 5 blows with increased damage, you can use something

```
private float _damage = 10;
private int _increasedBlows = 0; //amount of blows with increased damage
private float _increasingCoeff = 2; //ratio of damage increase of blow

//add new increased blows after doing combo
public void AddIncreasedBlows(int amount)
{
    _increasedBlows += amount;
}

//return blow damage
public float GetHitDamage()
{
    if (_increasedBlows > 0)
    {
        _increasedBlows--;
        return _damage * -_increasingCoeff; //return increased damage
    }
    else
    {
        return _damage; //return usual damage
    }
}
```